# Unable to see the image on the button in toolbar

Tags: java, swing, toolbar, imagebutton

I have been studying `swing` for developing gui applications since a few days.

The following code aims to create a **toolbar** with an exit **button** (including the **image** "exit.png"). The problem is I am unable to see the **image**, though the **toolbar** shows up. The **toolbar** is positioned `NORTH` using the **borderlayout** manager in java.

```
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");

    menubar.add(file);
    setJMenuBar(menubar);

    JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
    toolbar.setFloatable(false);

    ImageIcon exit = new ImageIcon("exit.png");
    JButton bexit = new JButton(exit);
    bexit.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    toolbar.add(bexit);
    //Default layout manager for JFrame is BorderLayout Manager
    add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

The code is written inside a class constructor where the class extends the `JFrame` swing class.

please note that I have imported the required classes. There is no compile error either. the image is saved in the directory where the .class is created. Other elements of the gui are displayed without an error.

Please help me identify the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create your ImageIcon.

```
ImageIcon myIcon = createImageIcon("exit.png", "");
```

And the code for the createImageIcon() method as found on the Oracle website:

```
private ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description) {
        URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
       } else {
          System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
          return null;
       }
    }
```

And then set the icon of the button with:

```
bexit.setIcon(myIcon);
```

Comment: the method belongs to which class?

Comment: Same class as your JFrame. Also have a look at the tutorial on the Oracle website: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Comment: got the answer!! new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("exit.png"));

Comment: Good answer +1. But I always put an icon to buttons with JButton be = new JButton(new ImageIcon("exit.png"); and works. I think the reason the code snippet provided by PVB is working, is the constructor used of ImageIcon, passing only the type String (the filename), and using it as initializer for an anonymous class in the button. --> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html

Comment: +1, since you did your job nicely for the person who asked it. Still he forgot to click on the right mark. 
Regards